# Import sha256WithRSAEncryption into java keystore

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, keytool

I have a key as follows-

> Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
>
> Subject Public Key Info:
>
> Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
>
> RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)

I then import it into the keystore with

> sudo /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-0.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -file /etc/cert.cer -keystore /etc/keystore.jks -alias "proofpoint"

When I come to use this in my jetty server I get

> java.security.PrivilegedActionException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common

thrown in sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.

Have I imported the key incorrectly?

Comment: What option is 'keytool -import -trustcacerts'? It is not in keytool documentation. ¿What are you trying to do with the certificate?

Comment: -import is the same as -importcert according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Comment: No relationship between the certificate import and the error. have you configured and SSL certificate? What action produces the handshake error? What client are you using? Please detail

Comment: what version of Jetty? (note: Jetty 9.3.x is **very** locked down)